# Nginx reverse proxy, only allow connection from hostname not ip

Tags: nginx, dns, reverse-proxy, hostname

Is it possible to allow only users typing in xxxxxx.com (fictive), so they should make a DNS-lookup and connect. And block users who uses my public ip to connect ?

Configuration:

```
server {
listen 80;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

listen 443;
server_name xxxxxxx.com;

ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

ssl on;
ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

access_log            /var/log/nginx/jenkins.access.log;

location / {

  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
  proxy_pass          http://10.0.11.32:80;
  proxy_read_tenter code hereimeout  360;

  proxy_redirect      http://10.0.11.32:80 https://xxxxxxx.com;
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$http_host` parameter is set to the value of the `Host` request header. `nginx` uses that value to select a `server` block. If a `server` block is not found, the default server is used, which is either marked as `default_server` or is the first `server` block encountered. See [this documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

To force `nginx` to only accept named requests, use a *catch all* server block to reject anything else, for example:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 403;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ...
}
```

With the SSL protocol, it depends on whether or not you have [SNI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#sni) enabled. If you are not using SNI, then all SSL requests pass through the same `server` block, in which case you will need to use an `if` directive to test the value of the `$http_host` value. See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) and [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) for details.