# Nginx: How to match ONLY the main domain with server_name

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, subdomain, virtualhost, ubuntu-19.10

My goal is to redirect `example.com` into `www.example.com` without redirecting **any** subdomain to `www`.

This is what I have:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

With this configuration **every** subdomain (ex: `foo.example.com`) gets redirected into `www.example.com`, not just the main one without subdomain (`example.com`), as I would like.

I tried cleaning cache (and also doing it from other browsers) with same results.

**Edit:**

The proof that the `server_name` is matching subdomains is that if I change the redirection url to: `https://www.$host$request_uri` then:

`foo.example.com` gets redirected to `www.foo.example.com`.

Comment: This server block is also the default server block that handles any request that doesn't match any server_name. See [how nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html). You need to define a catch-all server. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301884/nginx-reverse-proxy-only-allow-connection-from-hostname-not-ip/34307311#34307311).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `example.com` does only match the main domain.

But if the `hostname` doesn't match any `server_name` (and in your example, your subdomains do not as there is only one server rule for the main domain), the **default server** will be used, which, [if you didn't specify it with the `default_server` tag in the listen parameter, it uses by default the first server](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html), which, in your case, is the redirection rule for the main domain.

### TD;TR

Your subdomains aren't matching any rule, so they are being called back to the only rule you setted, the redirection.

You need to have a specific rule for subdomains:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name *.example.com;
  # do something, or leave it blank for default nginx page
}
```

This will prevent the subdomains from using the default server and so, being redirected to `www`, but they are not configured for doing nothing, so a default nginx page will show. I would recomend to directly specify the behaviour you want for each of the subdomains, or replacing the comment with the actual expected behaviour for all of them.

Comment: I like how working with HTML too much made you type `TD;TR` instead of `TL;TR` 
(haters will say TR;TD would make more sense)   ;)

Comment: @Vincent you read my mind

Answer (score 1):

Try using several `server_name` directives:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name ~^(?<name>\w+)\.example\.com$;
  
  ... # insert your directives (location etc.)
}
```

As specified on the [`nginx` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html):

> When searching for a virtual server by name, if name matches more
> than one of the specified variants, e.g. both wildcard name and
> regular expression match, the first matching variant will be chosen,
> in the following order of precedence:
>
> 1. exact name
> 2. longest wildcard name starting with an asterisk, e.g. “*.example.org”
> 3. longest wildcard name ending with an asterisk, e.g. “mail.*”
> 4. first matching regular expression (in order of appearance in a configuration file)

Comment: It seems a little bit odd to me redirecting foo.example.com into foo.example.com

Comment: As I expected, this causes a redirection loop.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `return` for the foo.example.org?

Comment: Ok. I needed an specific rule for the subdomains.

Comment: Your update solution may work, but I think is better to use * as wildcard instead of regex.
It was helpful, so +1 for your approach.

Comment: Also, that documentation you linked only applies when it matches more than one server names, and in my case I only have one, so It doesn't answer the question Why does example.com match subdomains?