# Why does example.com behave exactly as .example.com?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I don't know why `server_name` example.com matches also subdomains (at least when there's not a rule for those), if there's an specific syntax for doing so:

Nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) states that you can define `server_name` in the following ways:

> Sets names of a virtual server, for example:
>
> ```
> server_name example.com;
> ```
>
> Server names can include an asterisk (“*”) replacing the first or last
> part of a name:
>
> ```
> server_name *.example.com;
> ```
>
> Such names are called wildcard names.
>
> The first two of the names mentioned above can be combined in one:
>
> ```
> server_name .example.com;
> ```

But I tested this, and `example.com` behaves just as `.example.com` is expected, matching also all the subdomains.

This is not a problem as I can override the subdomains by setting a server for  `*.example.com` but it seems very odd to me that if the syntax of `.example.com` exists with the intention to match both other two, it should mean that the other two don't match to eachother...

Why is this?

Comment: One of the available `server` blocks for each listening port/network interface always acts as the default sever capturing all the incoming requests on that port/interface no matter of HTTP `Host` header value. The default server can be defined explicitly with the `default_server` flag of the `listen` directive otherwise it would be the first `server` block listening on that IP/port combination. Read [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) documentation page.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362642/nginx-doesnt-listen-on-port-80-twice/60362700#60362700) is more detailed answer on that subject.

Comment: Nice, thank you. If you post just that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Further explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64742545/8719655

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your subdomains don't match any rule, they will be called back to the rule tagged as `default_server`, which, by default, is the first one on the file. In this case, the `example.com` rule.

This is the answer to the right question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64742545/8719655