# Newbie - how do I configure NGINX to only serve request from a specific domain?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm new to NGINX so I might be missing some basic knowledge.

Looking at the server block below, I would expect NGINX to only show http://localhost if the request header contains [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or example.com as domain.

But all domains - no matter their name - will be directed to http://localhost

So if I type the address [www.abc.com:91](http://www.abc.com:91) it will also show http://localhost.

How do I configure NGINX to only show http://localhost if the request comes from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or example.com ?

Thanks

```
    server {
     listen   91;
     server_name  www.example.com example.com;
         location / {
          proxy_pass_request_headers on;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr:$server_port;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for:$server_port;
          proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
          proxy_pass http://localhost;  
         }
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301884/nginx-reverse-proxy-only-allow-connection-from-hostname-not-ip/34307311#34307311)

Comment: @RichardSmith - Thanks. A catch all was what I needed. Thanks !!